# Subspace of Vector Space $\mathbb R^3$ over the field $\mathbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V = \mathbb R^3$ be a vector space over the field $\mathbb R$, Let $U = \{(x,y,x+y)\ x,y \in \mathbb R \}$, then is it true that $U$ is a subspace of $V$?

Answer:

Yes, $U$ is a subspace of $V$, because $u_1,u_2 \in U$ then $u_1 + u_2$  $\in U$, also for every $a \in F$ then $au_1 \in U$. Also $0$ lies in $U$..
Let $u_1 \in U$ then $u_1=(x_1,y_1,x_1+y_1)$, and let $u_2 \in U$ then $u_2 = (x_2,y_2,x_2+y_2)$

$u_1+u_2=(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2,(x_1+x_2)+(y_1+y_2))$, hence $u_1+u_2 \in U$...Similarly

$a \in \mathbb R$ and $u_1=(x_1,y_1,x_1+y_1)$ then $au_1=a(x_1,y_1,x_1+y_1)=(ax_1,ay_1,ax_1+ay_1)$...

when $x_1=y_1=0, (0,0,0)$ also lies in $U$..Hence $U$ is a subspace..Am i right?

Please tell me where i am wrong...

Comment: Just elaborate more: for example, give more details on "then" part.

Comment: It looks fine, and I agree with Solitary: elaborate a little more in proving each of those properties.

Comment: Up to misreading, and if $ F=\Bbb R $, I wouldn't say you are.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I am sorry, i did not get you...

Comment: I just said that I do not think you are wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've merely restated the definition of a subspace without actually proving that $U$ is a subspace.

The most efficient way to prove that a given set is a subspace is to use the [one-step vector subspace test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Vector_Subspace_Test).

In our case, note that $U\neq\varnothing$ since $\mathbf 0\in U$.

Let $(u,v,u+v),(x,y,x+y)\in U$ and let $\lambda\in\Bbb R$. Then
$$
(u,v,u+v)+\lambda(x,y,x+y)=(u+\lambda x, v+\lambda y, u+\lambda x+v+\lambda y)\in U
$$
Hence $U$ is a subspace.

Alternatively, you could note that $U$ is the [column space](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Column_Space) of the matrix
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
and note that the column space of any $m\times n$ matrix is a subspace of $\Bbb R^m$.